# How can I display one product using WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I can't seem to find the function that does this I the API docs of WooCommerce. Is the a function that allows me to display one a couple of products that are under a specific category or tag?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce product is just a custom post type. You can use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`.

Comment: What about if I want to get all the products under a certain category?